# Registering a bean programmatically in the testing BootstrapContext?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm working on an integration with an older library so that it can use Spring Boot testing, and for that I need to register a certain bean very early in the process, so that an `ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent>` can add a `PropertySource` to the `Environment`.

This works fine in the normal startup, but when using the `@SpringBootTest` annotation I need to be able to inspect the `TestContext` very early and add it to the testing `BootstrapContext`, so that the application listener can access it also in the integration tests.

But I can't find a good way to add bean instances to the test `BootstrapContext` apart from specifying an initializer class in the `spring.factories` files, or am I missing something here?

I have been looking into using `@BootstrapWith` and subclassing `SpringBootContextBootstrapper`, but can't seem to find a way to add some kind of `BootstrapregistryInitializer`-like functions?

Comment: Shouldn't you be using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` instead of an `ApplicationListener` for that? Which then should also work in your test.

Comment: But maybe show more of what you are doing in your regular application (maybe that can be improved/made easier so that it works for testing as well).

Comment: Ah, using an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` might work! Thanks for the tip - I'll take a look and get back.